# What is the Thales HSM BA command to encrypt clear PIN

Tags: encryption, hsm

So I am new to HSM encryption. We have a Thales PayShield 9000 HSM and the requirement is to encrypt a clear PIN using the ISO 9564 Format 0 standard.

What I have is the following:

> Message Header: 00000000
>
> Clear PIN:  1111
>
> PAN: 6999999999999992
>
> PIN Encryption Key (32):  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

My requirement is to use the `BA` hsm command to encrypt PIN 1111 to get a 16  hex Pin Block. I have tried

```
00000000BA1111FFFFFFFFFF999999999999XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

But I got response `15`, can someone assist advise what is the correct command format or example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'BA' would encrypt the clear pin using LMK of HSM, it would not encrypt the pin using the ZPK

So first you should use BA command(remove the ZPK from your command) to get the pin encrypted under the LMK, then you can use 'JG' to translate the pin from LMK to ZPK.

Answer (score 0):

You must check the HSM security setting "Encrypted PIN length', and right-pad your PIN with Fs to this length.
So if the encrypted PIN length = 5 and clear PIN = 1111 ==> input value is 1111F.

Also you don't send any PIN key (ZPK), because BA command encrypts PIN under LMK. If you need PIN encrypted under ZPK, use both BA and JG commands.

So your command should look like (if encrypted PIN length = 5)
00000000BA1111F999999999999